Rewriting SDE as stochastic integral
Consider the process
$$ Y(t) = \int_0^t AY(s) ds + X(s)$$
where $A$ is some operator and $X$ is a martingale. Can we also express $Y$ as
$$ Y(t) = \int_0^t e^{As} dX(s)$$
where $e^{As}$ is the infinitesimal generator associated with the operator $A$?
I'm not sure why this would be true, I just read in a paper something that implied a relationship like this would exist.

"Something like" that $Y(t) = e^{At}\int_0^t e^{-As},dX(s)$ looks better. Use Ito to see why and please fix a typo in your first equation: $X(t),.$

@KurtG. Thank you! Ito's formula is for expanding the differential of a function $f$ of a stochastic process, right? What is that $f$ here?

$f(x,y)=xy$ where $e^{At}$ goes into one slot and the stochastic integral into the other.

@KurtG. I attempted what you suggested. Ran into some troubles. See the community wiki I posted. I never took a class on stochastic calculus, so I guess basic things are tripping me up.

Your guess is correct. Do you think it  a good way of learning stochastic calculus by throwing the above question at the MSE community? Standard textbooks are there for that purpose. Besides: I strongly recommend to learn these things when $A$ is not an operator. Take $X$ to be $\mathbb R$-valued and let $A$ be just a number.

@KurtG. thanks for the help, I'll try that. MSE is a learning tool.
